# How to input a different varaible as input at readline in R?

Tags: r

Code:

```
a1<-10

b1<-readline("Enter Value: ")
```

Prompt And Output

```
 b1<-readline("Enter Value: ")
 Enter Value: a1
 > b1
 [1] "a1"
```

Desired Output

```
 b1<-readline("Enter Value: ")
 Enter Value: a1
 > b1
 [1] 10
```

How do I get the value of b1 to be 10 instead of 'a1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get`:

```
b1 <- get(readline("Enter Value: "))
Enter Value: a1
> b1
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

[`base::get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).  Change that last line from `b1` to `get(b1)`.

```
a1 <- 10

# b1<-readline("Enter Value: ")
b1 <- "a1"
get(b1) # Returns `[1] 10`
```